# PowerBI PDF Export Random White Space - Padding

Tags: powerbi

Power BI Desktop Pro Version :

Exporting a PDF is adding some random padding around the PDF I've tried messing with all the display options Fit to Page, fit to width, actual size but no cigar.

has anyone played around with this with a solution? nothing really came up from google searches..?

The image is set via the filter pane and page background property.

current resolution is set to 1440 x 1024 pixels.

[image: PowerBI PDF]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gaps are the default PDF margins, so it is rendering the report correctly and not cropping the report. The margin will be wider at the top that the sides as it fitting the 16:9 standard report ration, to the A4 size. Exporting in PowerPoint will also render the image with a small boarder to the left and the right. One work around would be to export the report in Power Point, adjust the scale of the images then convert to PDF

Hope that helps